# insertRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadData doesn't respond

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is my code. And yesterday it works just fine. But this morning, it doesn't work.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        RSDrug *drug = [[RSDrug alloc]init];
        [drugArray insertObject:drug atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return drugArray.count + 1;
}
```

I have tried to add some code like beginUpdates/endUpdates, or I delete insertRowsAtIndexPaths, just use reloadData.

But same result. When the app runs to insertRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadData, it stuck, no response.

So I need some help. How to solve this?

**Found the problem..........A stupid mistake**

There are two UITextFields in the added cell, and they all have the same leftView, my code is like this:

```
UIImageView *leftImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
field_1.leftView = leftImage;
field_2.leftView = leftImage;
```

I never know that I **can't** reuse the leftView. If I set the leftImage to field1, I can't set it to field2 anymore.

When I changed to this, it works again.

```
field_1.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
field_2.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RSDrug *drug = [[RSDrug alloc]init];

[drugArray insertObject:drug atIndex:0];
[tableView beginUpdates];

    // indexpath inserted is with the index 0 same with the `insertObject: `
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    //here is what i use to do instead of @[]
    //[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

**EDIT**
Your code are working fine. i tested it. here..

**Code:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Log:**

[image]

Check the tested code above if you have omitted something.

I think the problem is the delegates of your table, make sure that your table have the delegate for both `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate`.

Hope this is helpful.. Cheers.. :)

Comment: I know if I write indexPathForRow:0 it will work, but it's not what I need. By default, my tableview has one row, this row works as a button, I clicked it, tableview add a row. And always add it at row 2, so I have to use indexPathForRow:1.

Comment: Ahhh.. okay.. so this `[drugArray insertObject:drug atIndex:0];` should be `[drugArray insertObject:drug atIndex:1];`  and `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];`?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection return drugArray.count + 1;` by default, drugArray is an empty array, when clicked the first row, it will add a object. So the index is 0; I think the indexes are all right, because these code works fine before, but I don't know why it doesn't work anyone, I haven't do any change between yesterday and this morning.

Comment: @ghysrc, there check it out.. :)

Comment: Well, I found the stupid mistake, you can see it from my last edit. Sorry for wasting you time. Thanks.

Comment: Haha.. ;) That happen sometime dont say sorry.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence...

```
NSMutableArray *indexPaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView beginUpdates];

    RSDrug *drug = [[RSDrug alloc]init];
    [drugArray insertObject:drug atIndex:0];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [indexPaths removeAllObjects];

        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row++   inSection:0]];  // here inserting row index=1;

        [tableViewMenuList insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Still, not work. And I really can't figure out why it worked yesterday. This morning I open my computer, run again, same code, doesn't work anymore.